Help identifying a war movie set in a fort in the desert
I'm trying to remember a movie with only knowing certain details. I remember it was about a man who was in the military. He was stationed at a fort somewhere in the desert. The fort was often under attack by Arabians with machine guns on horseback.
I remember a scene where he had to shoot his friend who got captured and who was being tortured.
In the end the Arabian soldiers invaded the fort and killed everyone except him. He was the last man and the last scene ends with him walking among the Arabians who where cheering loudly because they won.
I really hope I gave enough details for someone to figure out the title of the movie. I would really appreciate it.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

You may also be thinking of one of the various versions of Beau Gest: 
1926 starring Ronald Coleman 
1939 starring Gary Cooper 
1966 starring Guy Stockwell

That description sounds a lot like Legionnaire starring Jean Claude Van Damme.

"Man who was in the military", check.  He starts out elsewhere (a boxer in Marseille), but soon joins the French Foreign Legion.  
"Stationed at a fort somewhere in the desert", check.  He is sent to North Africa to help defend Morocco.  Lots of sand.
"Fort was under attack by Arabians", check.  "..a native Berber rebellion of Rif warriors, led by Abd el-Krim."  They had machine guns (plus explosives and a cannon).
"In the end the Arabian soldiers invaded the fort and killed everyone except him."  He is the last man standing.
"The last scene ends with him walking among the Arabians who where cheering loudly because they won", check.  The leader gives him a warning to deliver to the French and allows him to leave.

I don't quite recall the scene where he kills someone being tortured, but can remember there were several times they had to 'be cruel to be kind' with one of their comrades in arms.

As an aside, I'm not entirely confident about the Berber fighters armed with 'machine guns', I do remember them having lots of rifles though. The Legionnares probably had the larger 'fixed location' (on a tripod or other mount) type machine guns.

Your description sounds like "The Lost Patrol", a 1934 film, and one of my personal favorites.
IMDb:

A World War I British Army patrol is crossing the Mesopotomian desert when their commanding officer, the only one who knows their destination is killed by the bullet of unseen bandits. The patrol's sergeant keeps them heading north on the assumption that they will hit their brigade. They stop for the night at an oasis and awake the next morning to find their horses stolen, their sentry dead, the oasis surrounded and survival difficult. 




